# OpenSSL Encrypt / Decrypt only decrypting the first 7 or so characters?

Tags: c, openssl, passwords

I'm having a little trouble getting two program to encrypt and decrypt a message using openssl.  The two programs compile and run fine, but the decrypt seems to only decrypt the first 7 or so characters of my plaintext.txt file.

after making the file encrypt and decrypt are called from command line like this...

./enc -i plaintext.txt -o cipher.txt -p password

./dec i- cipher.txt -o decrypt.txt -p password

plaintext.txt input is...
This is something to keep secret

decrypt.txt output is...
This is }?w,

Here is enc.c (encryption)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

/* AES-GCM test data from NIST public test vectors */

static const unsigned char gcm_iv[] = {
    0x99, 0xaa, 0x3e, 0x68, 0xed, 0x81, 0x73, 0xa0, 0xee, 0xd0, 0x66, 0x84
};

unsigned char * aes_gcm_encrypt(unsigned char *pt, long size, unsigned char *myCipher, unsigned char *out)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int outlen, tmplen;
    unsigned char outbuf[1024];
  //  printf("AES GCM Encrypt:\n");
//    printf("Plaintext:\n");
  //  BIO_dump_fp(stdout, pt, size);
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    /* Set cipher type and mode */
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    /* Set IV length if default 96 bits is not appropriate */
   // EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_IVLEN, sizeof(out), NULL);
    /* Initialise key and IV */
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, out, gcm_iv);
    /* Encrypt plaintext */
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, pt, sizeof(pt));
    /* Output encrypted block */
  //  printf("Ciphertext:\n");
  //  BIO_dump_fp(stdout, outbuf, size);
    /* Finalise: note get no output for GCM */
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &outlen);


    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return myCipher = outbuf;
}


    extern int errno;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int ITERATION = 10000;
    FILE * fp;
    int errnum;
    long size;  
    unsigned char *pass;
    int len;
    pass = argv[6];


    fp = fopen(argv[2], "a+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("error printed by perror");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file: %s\n", strerror(errnum));
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char * buff;   
    buff = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*size + 1);
    memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(unsigned char)*size + 1);
    fread(buff, 1, size, fp);

    int SHA1_LEN = 30;
    unsigned char* out = (unsigned char*)calloc(SHA1_LEN, sizeof(unsigned char));
    //int SALT_LEN = 5;
    //RAND_bytes(salt, SALT_LEN);

    pass = argv[6];
    printf("Test print of pass: %s\n", pass);   
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pass, strlen(pass), NULL, 0, ITERATION, SHA1_LEN, out);

    printf("PASSWORD ENCRYPT: ");   
    printf("%s\n", out);

    unsigned char *myCipher;

    myCipher = aes_gcm_encrypt(buff, size, myCipher, out);

    //printf("%s\n", myCipher);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(argv[4], "w+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("error printed by perror");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file: %s\n", strerror(errnum));
    }

    fputs(myCipher, fp);

    printf("CIPHER TEXT: %s\n", myCipher);

    printf("\n");   
    fclose(fp); 


    return 0;
}
```

Here is dec.c (decryption)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>


static const unsigned char gcm_iv[] = {
    0x99, 0xaa, 0x3e, 0x68, 0xed, 0x81, 0x73, 0xa0, 0xee, 0xd0, 0x66, 0x84
};

unsigned char * aes_gcm_decrypt(unsigned char *pt, long size, unsigned char *myPlainText, unsigned char *out)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int outlen, tmplen, rv;
    unsigned char outbuf[1024];
    //printf("AES GCM Derypt:\n");
    //printf("Ciphertext:\n");
    //BIO_dump_fp(stdout, pt, size);
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    /* Select cipher */
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    /* Set IV length, omit for 96 bits */
  //  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_IVLEN, sizeof(gcm_iv), NULL);
    /* Specify key and IV */
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, out, gcm_iv);

    /* Decrypt plaintext */
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, pt, sizeof(pt));
    /* Output decrypted block */
  //  printf("Plaintext:\n");
    //BIO_dump_fp(stdout, outbuf, size);

    rv = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &outlen);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return myPlainText = outbuf;

}

    extern int errno;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int ITERATION = 10000;
    FILE * fp;
    int errnum;
    long size;  
    unsigned char *pass;
    int len;
    pass = argv[6];


    fp = fopen(argv[2], "a+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("error printed by perror");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file: %s\n", strerror(errnum));
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char * buff;   
    buff = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*size + 1);
    memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(unsigned char)*size + 1);
    fread(buff, 1, size, fp);

    int SHA1_LEN = 30;
    unsigned char* out = (unsigned char*)calloc(SHA1_LEN, sizeof(unsigned char));

    pass = argv[6];
    printf("Test print of pass: %s\n", pass);   
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pass, strlen(pass), NULL, 0, ITERATION, SHA1_LEN, out);

    printf("PASSWORD ENCRYPT: ");   
    printf("%s\n", out);

    unsigned char *myPlainText;

    myPlainText =  aes_gcm_decrypt(buff, size, myPlainText, out);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(argv[4], "w+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("error printed by perror");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file: %s\n", strerror(errnum));
    }

    fputs(myPlainText, fp);

    printf("PLAINTEXT: %s\n", myPlainText); 
    printf("\n");   
    fclose(fp); 


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without detailed knowledge of ssl my guess is that these calls

`EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, pt, sizeof(pt));`

`EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, pt, sizeof(pt));`

should have size of what pt points to instead of size of a pointer.

`EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, pt, ptlen);`

`EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, pt, ptlen);`

where ptlen is size of buffer pt points to.

Looking at [openssl manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/evp.html) confirms my guess:

EVP_EncryptUpdate() encrypts inl bytes from the buffer in and writes the encrypted version to out. This function can be called multiple times to encrypt successive blocks of data. The amount of data written depends on the block alignment of the encrypted data: as a result the amount of data written may be anything from zero bytes to (inl + cipher_block_size - 1) so out should contain sufficient room. The actual number of bytes written is placed in outl.

EVP_DecryptInit_ex(), EVP_DecryptUpdate() and EVP_DecryptFinal_ex() are the corresponding decryption operations. EVP_DecryptFinal() will return an error code if padding is enabled and the final block is not correctly formatted. The parameters and restrictions are identical to the encryption operations except that if padding is enabled the decrypted data buffer out passed to EVP_DecryptUpdate() should have sufficient room for (inl + cipher_block_size) bytes unless the cipher block size is 1 in which case inl bytes is sufficien